# Akka-Persistence database vs actor existence

Tags: akka, akka-http, akka-persistence

Assuming I have an actor system (Parent/Child/GrandChild) and am using Akka-Persistence. If I want a user to be able to query an endpoint to read information about an actor e.g. `GET /{parent-id}/{child-id}/{grandchild-id}` if the parent does not exist when I call `system.actorSelection("parent-$parent-id")` how can I be sure that it actually does not exist (in the DB) rather than just the actor not being alive e.g. the service was restarted?

Should Akka persistent applications always have all persisted actors in memory at the same time? And if so how do you manage large data applications where it is not beneficial to have all the data in-memory at the same time?

Thanks,

Ben